# ASP.NET Core: Can not resolve a service instance through CallContextServiceLocator.Locator.ServiceProvider

Tags: asp.net-core

This is part of my `ConfigureServices` method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    //bus
    services.AddSingleton<IRouteMessages, MessageRouter>();
    services.AddSingleton<IBus, DirectBus>();
    ////

   ...

}
```

I'm trying to resolve the instance of `IRouteMessages` interface in my `RegisterCommandHandlersInMessageRouter` class:

```
public class RegisterCommandHandlersInMessageRouter
{
    ...

    public static void BootStrap()
    {
        var router = CallContextServiceLocator.Locator.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof (IRouteMessages));
        new RegisterCommandHandlersInMessageRouter().RegisterRoutes(router as MessageRouter);
    }

    ...

}
```

`router` variable is always null. Yet in my controllers where `IRouterMessages` is resolved automatically (in constructors) everything is fine.

I'm not sure what other parts of my code could be useful. I will provide more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't **EVER** use `CallContextServiceLocator`, this completely beats the purpose of having dependency injection. And **NEVER** relay on it.

`CallContextServiceLocator` is only used in some of the internal ASP.NET Core and is never be supposed to be used by developers creating ASP.NET Core applications. That being said, it can be removed, made internal or inaccessible at any time which would break existing applications.

Additionally, the `CallContextServiceLocator` only had runtime services registered (DNX Services, deprecated anyways). Source: [David Fowl](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/3242#issuecomment-163579188) from ASP.NET Core team.

Infact `CallContextServiceLocator` is being removed in RC2, see the [announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/106).

> 4. Removed support for  `CallContextServiceLocator`. Use  `PlatformServices` and `CompilationServices` instead.

Instead, only use the built-in dependency injection, like this:

```
public static class RegisterCommandHandlersInMessageRouter
{
    ...
    // This is extension method now
    public static void RegisterCommandHandlers(this IServiceProvider services)
    {
        var router = services.GetService(typeof (IRouteMessages));
        new RegisterCommandHandlersInMessageRouter().RegisterRoutes(router as MessageRouter);
    }

    ...

}
```

and call it in your Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IServiceProvider services) 
{
    ...
    services.RegisterCommandHandlers();
    ...
}
```